# SQL Busqueda en cascada

Tags: sql-server-2012

Buen dia!

Tengo una duda, necesito realizar una búsqueda en cascada con un string en los siguientes 5 escenarios:

> Escenario1: string = 'valor1 valor2 valor3 valor4 valor5'
>   Escenario2: string = 'valor1 valor2 valor3 valor4'
>  Escenario3:
>   string = 'valor1 valor2 valor3'
>  Escenario4: string = 'valor1
>   valor2'
>  Escenario5: string = 'valor1'

La búsqueda debe realizarse en cascada en una tabla que contiene un campo para cada valor, quedando mas o menos asi:

Para escenario 1:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Tabla'<br>
WHERE 'Campo1' = 'valor1'<br>
  AND 'Campo2' = 'valor2'<br>
  AND 'Campo3' = 'valor3'<br>
  AND 'Campo4' = 'valor4'<br>
  AND 'Campo5' = 'valor5'<br>
```

Para escenario 2:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Tabla'<br>
WHERE 'Campo1' = 'valor1'<br>
  AND 'Campo2' = 'valor2'<br>
  AND 'Campo3' = 'valor3'<br>
  AND 'Campo4' = 'valor4'<br>
```

Y asi sucesivamente...

La duda es: ¿de que manera puedo separar esa cadena de valor para abarcar los 5 escenarios que seran variables?

¿La funcionalidad de 'full-text search' me podria servir para realizar las busquedas en la tabla usando el string directamente como variable en el query?

Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias.

Comment: El escenario de que depende? es decir se podría definir "a priori" una variable @escenario que establezca de que escenario se trata?

Comment: Una disculpa @PatricioMoracho, no habia visto tu comentario, ya quedo resuelto en la parte de abajo, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien, puedes usar algo asi :

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(10), @v2 VARCHAR(10), @v3 VARCHAR(10), @v4 VARCHAR(10), @v5 VARCHAR(10), @var INT, @x VARCHAR(1000), @temp VARCHAR(100)

SET @x = 'COHD910745GV1 123211471 910709 DFSDC412 SDFSD3210'
SET @var = 0

WHILE (CHARINDEX(' ', LTrim(RTRIM(@x)))>0)
BEGIN 
    SET @var= @var + 1
    SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@x, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', LTrim(RTRIM(@x))))
    SET @x = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@x, @temp, '')))

    if @var = 1
        SET @v1 = @temp
    if @var = 2
        SET @v2 = @temp
    if @var = 3
        SET @v3 = @temp
    if @var = 4
        SET @v4 = @temp
END

if @v1 is NULL
    SET @v1 = @x
else
    IF @v2 is NULL
        SET @v2 = @x
    ELSE
        if @v3 is NULL
            set @v3 = @x
        ELSE
            IF @v4 is NULL
                SET @v4 = @x
            ELSE
                SET @v5 = @x

SELECT * FROM 'Tabla'
WHERE (Campo1 is null or Campo1 = @v1)
AND (Campo2 is null or Campo2 = @v2)
AND (Campo3 is null or Campo3 = @v3)
AND (Campo4 is null or Campo4 = @v4)
AND (Campo5 is null or Campo5 = @v5)
```

Y asi haces que el where sea condicional, si inicializas el valor se hara ese filtro, si todos los valores son nulos, retornara todos los registros.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Mauricio, pero no es el escenario que expongo, el query recibira por ejemplo una cadena con los siguientes valores: x = 'COHD910745GV1 123211471 910709 DFSDC412 SDFSD3210'... como puedes ver esa cadena tiene 5 valores, lo que necesito es separarlos en 5 variables y buscar cada variable en su respectivo campo de la tabla (Hay que recordar que a veces esa cadena solo puede tener 4 valores o 3 valores, etc). Espero me haya dado a entender.

Comment: Por favor revisa el cambio  que te envié a ver si cumple...

Comment: Te agradezco infinitamente @Mauricio Atanache, tu respuesta fue la correcta, solamente tuve que modificar un poco el ultimo select quedando `SELECT * FROM Personas
WHERE RFC = ISNULL(@v1, RFC)
AND IMSS = ISNULL(@v2, IMSS)
AND Serie = ISNULL(@v3, Serie)
AND Cartilla = ISNULL(@v4, Cartilla)
AND Antecedentes = ISNULL(@v5, Antecedentes)` para que abarcara el escenario donde alguna variable fuera NULL, me has sacado de un apuro, gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tu variable string puede contener hasta 5 valores diferentes, de ser así un truco que te puede ayudar sería que concatenes el lado izquierdo de la condición para así compararlo con tu variable, es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Tabla'
WHERE 'Campo1' + ' ' 
    + 'Campo2' + ' ' 
    + 'Campo3' + ' ' 
    + 'Campo4' + ' ' 
    + 'Campo5' like '%' + string + '%'
```

Con ello no te preocuparías en descomponer tu string, sino mas bien de que concatenar correctamente tus columnas.

**Contras:**

- Si el orden de los valores en el 'string' es cambiante, no bastará concatenando en un solo orden las columnas.
- El performance se verá afectado un poco ya que la condición no trabaja sobre columnas indexadas.

Espero haber ayudado, saludos.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu idea. Podrias aterrizarlo con la siguiente informacion por favor: string = 'Diego CYHD412317HU1 01091991 16542147 8117481546'. Donde los valores estan relacionados con las columnas 'Nombre', 'RFC', 'FechaNacimiento', 'NSS', 'Celular' de la tabla 'Personas'.